# What is the main difference between $.ajax and $.post?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

In my project there are $.ajax calls and some $.post calls.

I think both are same!

Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `$.ajax` you can make different types of request to the url like get, post whereas `$.post` makes a post request to the url. You can also add Header parameters with `$.ajax`

Comment: Cheers mate. :)